# How to cast between interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm surprised I cannot cast between interfaces.

```
interface IA {
    a:string;
}

interface IB {
    b:string;   
}

class example implements IA, IB {
    public a:string;
    public b:string;
}

var a : IA = new example();

// nope - "Neither IA nor IB are assignable to each other"
var b : IB = <IB>(a);
```

What is the expected way of doing this. Casting via any?

```
// ok
var c : IB = <IB><any>(a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `example`, it will happy accept a type assertion to either `IA` or `IB` because it is compatible with both of those types.

`IA` is not compatible with `IB`, so the compiler will warn you if you attempt to use a type assertion.

You can perform a type safe widening using the following:

```
var c : IB = <example> a;
```

Or if you need to juggle totally incompatible types, you would have to widen to `any` first:

```
var c: IB = <IB><any>(crazy);
```

My preferred code would actually be to change this line - in which case you don't need to juggle things so much (i.e. let the compiler know you have an instance of `example`:

```
var a = new example();
```

> The purpose of casting is to tell the compiler you want to use an instance as a type it can't deduce. Preventing casting between interfaces just seems inconsistent, non-useful and doesn't prevent any errors. I can't see why it doesn't follow C# and behave like down casting classes.

The example supplied above is checked, so is type-safe.

```
// Allowed
var c : IB = <example> a;

// Not Allowed
var c : IB = <example> "test";
```

So although you are suggesting the widened type for the `a` variable, it is equivalent to C#, in that the compiler knows that `a` is compatible with `example` as well as `IA`. The difference is that this type information is structural, not nominal. `a` may also be compatible with many other types in your application - especially if you are an advocate of the interface segregation principle.

Disallowing a direct use of `IA` in a variable with type `IB` prevents you from assigning incompatible types. The types are checked first, but the structure is available too.

It is entirely possible for another programmer to assign `{a: 'x'}` to the `a` variable. At this point, you will be glad that TypeScript warns you that the type cannot be widened to `example` using the code above as it is right and it just prevented a runtime error.

You can achieve exactly what you want either by:

1. Declaring `a` as being of type `example` - this is how you intend to use the variable so is pretty honest.
2. Declaring `a` as being of type `IA`, using the type-safe widening to `example` when you want to use members from `example`. The widening is checked by the compiler.
3. Declare `a` as being of type `any`. If you think you know better than the compiler, you can have total control and responsibility.

So you can choose what level of control you want to take from the compiler. My recommendation is the first option above - use the type that reflects how you will actually use the value. This is closest to what you will be used to in C# as if you have a method that accepts an `IEnumerable` you wouldn't start trying to cast it to a `List` inside the method. If you needed a list, you'd ensure the method signature asked for one (while acknowledging the principle of asking for general types and returning specific ones).

Comment: The purpose of casting is to tell the compiler you want to use an instance as a type it can't deduce. Preventing casting between interfaces just seems inconsistent, non-useful and doesn't prevent any errors. I can't see why it doesn't follow C# and behave like down casting classes.

Comment: @daw I have added more information to my answer, rather than trying to squeeze it all in here.

Comment: Awesome, nice addition, thanks. The structural typing is the key insight for the difference. As you can expect, the example isn't like real world use which is more like e.g. Merge(a : IThing, b : IThing) where IThing needs to be downcast to something concrete to be implemented.